# JFrog Artifactory artifacts uploaded via jenkins dont show up in builds

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I use Jenkins to build my project, once that is done I upload the directory with all artifact files or just a single file to JFrog.
Pipeline-code example:

```
def server = Artifactory.server "jfrog1"

sh "touch uploadconfig.json"
writeFile(file: "uploadconfig.json", text: "{ \"files\": [ { \"pattern\": \"./uploadconfig.json\", \"target\": \"test-generic-local/uploadconfig1.json\", \"flat\" : \"true\" }]}")

uploadSpec = readFile 'uploadconfig.json'
uploadInfo = server.upload spec: uploadSpec
```

When the file is uploaded it has the build.name and build.number property.

But my issue is it will not show up under Artifactory -> Builds.

This is an issue since I want to have the option to download the latest file from this build using:

```
"files": [
        {
            "pattern": "test-generic-local/uploadconfig*",
            "target": "./",
            "build" : "nameOfMyJenkinsJob/LATEST"
        }
    ]
```

When I try to run it now without the artifacts being listed under Build I get the following error message:

The build name *nameOfMyJenkinsJob* could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are not publishing the build to Artifactory. Kindly refer to this JFrog [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-PublishingBuild-InfotoArtifactory) on how to publish the build info. Also, I would recommend you referring this [Github](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/maven-example/Jenkinsfile) Jenkins file where in the build publish stage is where the build is pushed.

Comment: Thanks I got it:
Just had to add the following
server.publishBuildInfo uploadInfo

Comment: Now I have the issue that the build shows up.
But "Number Of Artifacts" is 0 do you have a idea why that could be?

Comment: For anybody with the same issue.
For me it only showed the number of artifacts, if I specified the exact file I want to upload not just a patter for a whole folder.

Comment: It may be that the artifacts are uploaded with a different build name and/or build number than the build-info that is published. You can refer to these examples as a reference - https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples